# error make: *** No rule to make target `puff...."

Tags: makefile

I get error `` make: *** No rule to make target `puff' ``

My makefile code is

```
puff: puff.c puff.h
    cc -DTEST -o puff puff.c

test: puff
    puff zeros.raw

clean:
    rm -f puff puff.o
```

And in my directory I have files `puff.c`, `puff.h`, `zeros.raw`, `makefile`.
Please help — I'm stuck on it.

Comment: Where did the 4 dots in the subject come from?  What you've got looks about right, assuming you indent the commands with a tab (but you get a different error message if you get _that_ wrong).  What command are you typing exactly?  When I use `make -f puff.mk` (since I've already got a `makefile` in the directory), it works fine — on my code, obviously.

Comment: whats the exact command youre using to initiate make?

Answer (score -1):

you should write the command on the next line with a tab. The files on the same line as of target name are the dependencies. It should be like this

```
puff: puff.c puff.h 
    CC -DTEST -o puff puff.c
```

and similarly other rules. Don't forget to put a tab on the second line. These are not spaces but a tab. and also its CC I think, not cc.

Comment: `cc` (lower case) is usually the C compiler; `CC` (upper case) is sometimes the C++ compiler.  The macro is in upper case and written `$(CC)` or `${CC}` when used; it's written as `CC = cc` when it is defined (but `CC` is defined by `make` by default).

Comment: Since this is a question about `make` and C (not C++), the lower case `cc` in the compiler rule is probably correct and `CC` is probably incorrect.

Comment: CC is by default cc in make, for C++ compiler its CXX. You can check it from the official documentation. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Comment: The command part of the rule should be `${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $*.c` or something like that, though that's a trifle advanced and what the OP wrote in the question is acceptable when starting out.  (Also, it would be the default, more or less; `make` would use more or less that rule — with `${LDFLAGS}` and `${LDLIBS}` or thereabouts added at the end — to build a single-file C program anyway.) *IOW*, you're missing the point of my comments. Your statement that it should be `CC` instead of `cc` is wrong; the question was originally tagged `C` and not `C++`, so invoking the C++ compiler is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all characters after "puff:".

```
puff: 
    gcc -DTEST -o puff puff.c

test: puff
    puff zeros.raw

clean:
    rm -f puff puff.o
```

Comment: What difference would this make?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're right that `make` will infer the dependency on `puff.c`; it won't infer the dependency on `puff.h`.  (OTOH: a single file program doesn't need a separate header file; header files are for sharing information between source files, but there's only one file to use it.)  If it works after this, then there's probably some useful information in the fact that it works.  (Incidentally, when you're entering an answer — or question — there's a little **`{}`** button above the edit box which will indent the highlighted/selected code.)

Comment: those are dependencies on the same line, which are useful in this case. there is no point in removing those.

Comment: Thank Jonathan, I will learn more about writing good answsers or questions.

Comment: Now i get the error \ expected output, not standard error of "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4..."